# how to set [] as data attribute and get it using javascript / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

example:

```
data-value="[0]"
```

when I try to get the value with `jQuery(element).data('value')`, it always return "0". I also tried with toString() function or String object but failed, it keeps returning "0".

so how I can get the real value "[0]"?

Comment: `element.getAttribute('data-value')`

Comment: I am sorry i forgot to tell you i am using jquery and jquery add the prefix "data-" automatically.

Comment: how about using jquery Phil? how to do?

Comment: ahhhhhhh okay that makes sense. Thanks nnnnn and phil, it works now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jQuery(element).attr("data-value")
```

When you use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) it tries to be clever about what the data type is, but [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) just returns the string as is.

Expand and run the following snippet to see it working:

```js
$("p").click(function() {
  console.log("Value: " + $(this).attr("data-value"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p data-value="[0]">Zero</p>
<p data-value="[1]">One</p>
<p data-value="[2]">Two</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use jquery `attr()`method.

```js
console.log($("p").attr('data-value'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p data-value="[0]">
hi
</p>
```

OR

Using core **javascript**

```
value = document.querySelector('p').getAttribute('data-value');
alert(value);
```

Comment: i thought .data() is no different from getAttribute or .attr(). thanks!

Comment: yes these are different.The `data()` method attaches data to, or gets data from, selected elements(focus on datatype).but  the `attr()` method sets or returns attributes and values of the selected elements.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is your JQuery version, I did this on Chrome:
[image: console]

Comment: as seen as on the image, it convert to the real array not just string. if you try to show that value, it will appear "0" only. what i want to get is the real string :)

Comment: use JSON.stringify()!  just like JSON.stringify($('#test').data('value'))